# How do I address this 'subscript out of range error' in my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, subscript

I keep getting a 'Subscript out of range' error for the line: Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A4").Copy

I'm new to VBA so I'm sure there's something I'm missing-do you have any input?

The basis of this code is to input data from a userform into one sheet, and then copy that row of code to a different sheet in the first empty row.

Thank you in advance!!

```
    Private Sub EnterButton_Click()
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
   'Determine emptyRow
    emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    Sheet3.Activate

    'Transfer information
Cells(emptyrow, 1).Value = textbox1.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = textbox2.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = textbox3.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = textbox4.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = textbox5.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = textbox6.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = textbox7.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = textbox8.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = textbox9.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 11).Value = textbox11.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 12).Value = textbox12.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 13).Value = textbox13.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 14).Value = textbox14.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 17).Value = textbox17.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 18).Value = textbox18.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 19).Value = textbox19.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 20).Value = textbox20.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 21).Value = textbox21.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 25).Value = textbox25.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 26).Value = textbox26.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 27).Value = textbox27.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 28).Value = textbox28.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 29).Value = textbox29.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 33).Value = textbox33.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 34).Value = textbox34.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 35).Value = textbox35.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 36).Value = textbox36.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 37).Value = textbox37.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 41).Value = textbox41.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 42).Value = textbox42.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 43).Value = textbox43.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 44).Value = textbox44.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 45).Value = textbox45.Value
    
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A4").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A" & Rows.count_.End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: That means the active workbook has no sheet named "Sheet3".

Answer (score 0):

In your VBA Project, you most likely have something like `Sheet3("Name that appear in Excel")`. It would explain why this line works:

```
Sheet3.Activate
```

But not this one.

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A4").Copy
```

If you look at Sheet3 properties in VBA, you will that your Sheet `(Name)` is `Sheet3`, whereas your Sheet `Name` is different. The first is a VBA name, the second is the name that appear on your Excel workbook. You can change the second directly on Excel when you rename a tab.

With all those thing considered, this line should work:

```
Sheet3.range("A4").copy
```